# Setup Secure LDAP over SSL/TLS (LDAPS) for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ldap

Haven’t had much luck while trying several ways to implement LDAPS for PostgreSQL.

**pg_hba.conf**

```
hostssl all +test_ldap 0.0.0.0/0 ldap ldapserver=dc2.ad.foobar.com ldapport=636 ldapscheme=ldaps ldaptls=0 ldapbinddn="CN=ldap,OU=Helpers,OU=Foobar,DC=ad,DC=foobar,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd=*** ldapsearchattribute=mail ldapbasedn="OU=Users,OU=Foobar,DC=ad,DC=foobar,DC=com"
```

Upon [research](https://noobient.com/2019/01/31/postgresql-11-with-active-directory-over-ssl-on-centos-7/), I found out that the below params are to be changed.

**postgresql.conf**

```
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
```

The question is how do I get `.crt` and `.key` from the `.pem` certificate that I already have (shared by LDAP team). Apart from these what else needs to be done to make it work with LDAPS (SSL/TLS).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `ldaptls=1`.

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-ldap.html):

> `ldaptls`
>
> Set to 1 to make the connection between PostgreSQL and the LDAP server use TLS encryption. This uses the `StartTLS` operation per [RFC 4513](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4513). See also the `ldapscheme` option for an alternative.

I don't know what happens if you set both options to contradictory values, but it may well be the problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I have extended the answer.